# Where can I find the full lyrics for the song "War" by Caspa (feat. Keith Flint)?

Tags: lyrics

I couldn't find the complete lyrics of the song "War" by *Caspa (feat. Keith Flint)*.

Where can I find the actual lyrics for this track?

Comment: https://www.rockol.com/uk/lyrics-31899824/caspa-feat-keith-flint-war right here?

Comment: @OfirLana there is only chorus, the actual song also has Keef's lyrics parts.